# android - MaterialDatePicker Fullscreen: can't change black statusbar color

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

I have a problem with MaterialDatePicker. When I'm trying to open it in fullscreen, my statusbar becomes black. I've tried to create my own Theme with `parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen"` and override `statusBarColor` but it did nothing.

Also, I've tried to set `windowTranslucentStatus` - this is the only attribute I've found so far that applies a single change to statusbar. It becomes translucent but only a little and almost impossible to see.

The code I'm using to show MaterialDatePicker:

```
                val x = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                .setTitleText("Select period")
                .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen)
                .build()

            x.show(supportFragmentManager, "datePicker")
```

[image: Black statusbar]

Answer (score 0):

Change your app's theme to **Light** theme. For example,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Hope this helps.